# Como fazer uma borda estilizada?

Tags: css

Como fazer uma borda estilizada conforme imagem abaixo? A grande dúvida é que no lado esquerdo tem dois estilos de borda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A borda right e bottom é transparente?

Comment: Fiquei sem entender a sua pergunta, mas dá uma olhada [aqui](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/propriedades-css-para-estilizacao-de-bordas.php)

Comment: @MagicHat É sim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se a única borda estilizada assim for a esquerda, você pode trabalhar com os pseudo-elementos `:before` e `:after`, estilizando tanto suas bordas quanto seu corpo. Veja um exemplo onde criei a borda mais fina com o elemento `before` e o pequeno segmento cinza com o elemento `after`:

```css
.border {
  width: 300px;

  border-top: 3px solid #1E90FF;
  border-left: 3px solid #1E90FF;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: monospace
}

.border:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  left: -3px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  background: white;
}

.border:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  left: -2px;
  top: 100px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ornare, mi posuere suscipit malesuada, est ante tempor augue, quis porttitor lectus mauris ac diam. Morbi sed tortor justo. Etiam maximus orci magna, quis tristique dolor tempor id.
</div>
```

Comment: Bacana essa solução, mei custosa em termos de código, mas bacana e se for aplicada em vários elementos, deve ser mais leve que a imagem...

Comment: @MagicHat e utilizando o `calc` do CSS 3 é possível fazer bem dinâmico e responsivo. Com a imagem não lembro se é possível sem distorcê-la. Você sabe dizer?

Comment: ói, inda num testei, mas creio que se colocar os valores em porcentagem, "acho" que vai...[

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o atributo [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/border-image).

```html
<p id="borderimg">Utilize o atributo <strong>border-image</strong></p>
<style> 
#borderimg
{ width:300px;
  border: 30px solid transparent;
  padding: 20px;
  border-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnBXc.jpg") 27;
}
</style>
```

Verifique a compatibilidade entre os navegadores.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer algo como o exemplo abaixo:

```css
.border-on-top {
  border-top:1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
 
.half-a-border-on-left {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}
.half-a-border-on-left:after {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color:white;
  position: absolute;
  left:-1px;
  top: -10px;
}
.half-a-border-on-left:before {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 50%;
  background-color:blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-a-border-on-left border-on-top">Hello world!</div>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804417/css-border-where-only-half-of-a-border-is-visible